# how to reslove index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, class, smo

In smo algorithm and received an error as index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0.. since im new to python i got confused please help me with this...

```
        class SMO():
            def __init__(self,regularization_nn,learning_rate_RBM,learning_rate_nn,n_iter_RBM,batch_size_RBM,batch_size_nn,n_iter_nn):
                self.learning_rate_RBM=0.006
                self.learning_rate_nn=0.1
                self.n_iter_RBM=20
                self.batch_size_RBM=100
                self.batch_size_nn=100
                self.n_iter_nn=5000
                self.PopSize=batch_size_RBM
                self.dim=n_iter_RBM
                self.acc_err=batch_size_nn
                self.lb=learning_rate_RBM
                self.ub=learning_rate_nn
                self.objf=regularization_nn
                self.pos=numpy.zeros((batch_size_RBM,n_iter_RBM))
                self.fun_val = numpy.zeros(batch_size_RBM)
                self.fitness = numpy.zeros(batch_size_RBM)
                self.gpoint = numpy.zeros((batch_size_RBM,2))
                self.prob=numpy.zeros(batch_size_RBM)
                self.LocalLimit=n_iter_RBM*batch_size_RBM;
                self.GlobalLimit=batch_size_RBM;
                self.fit = numpy.zeros(batch_size_RBM)
                self.MinCost=numpy.zeros(n_iter_nn)
                self.Bestpos=numpy.zeros(n_iter_RBM)   

def initialize(self):
        global GlobalMin, GlobalLeaderPosition, GlobalLimitCount, LocalMin, LocalLimitCount, LocalLeaderPosition
        S_max=int(self.PopSize/2)
        LocalMin = numpy.zeros(S_max)
        LocalLeaderPosition=numpy.zeros((int(S_max),int(self.dim)))
        LocalLimitCount=numpy.zeros(S_max)
        for i in range(self.PopSize):
            print(i)
            for j in range(self.dim):
                if type(self.ub)==int:
                    self.pos[i,j]=random.random()*(self.ub-self.lb)+self.lb
                else:
                    self.pos[i,j]=random.random()*(self.ub[j]-self.lb[j])+self.lb[j]
        #Calculate objective function for each particle
        for i in range(self.PopSize):
            # Performing the bound checking
            self.pos[i,:]=numpy.clip(self.pos[i,:], self.lb, self.ub)
            self.fun_val[i]=self.objf(self.pos[i,:])
            self.func_eval+=1
            self.fitness[i]=self.CalculateFitness(self.fun_val[i])

        # Initialize Global Leader Learning
        GlobalMin=self.fun_val[0]
        GlobalLeaderPosition=self.pos[0,:]
        GlobalLimitCount=0

        # Initialize Local Leader Learning
        for k in range(self.group):
            LocalMin[k]=self.fun_val[int(self.gpoint[k,0])]
            LocalLimitCount[k]=0
            LocalLeaderPosition[k,:]=self.pos[int(self.gpoint[k,0]),:]
    # ============================================ X X X ======================================================= #
```

traceback error received in this run:

```
<ipython-input-23-1b18b438af48> in chimp_optimizer(X, Y, X_train, Y_train)
     16     #print(fopt)
     17 
---> 18     x,succ_rate,mean_feval = main(Deep_belief_network,X,Y,regularization_nn,learning_rate_RBM,learning_rate_nn,n_iter_RBM,batch_size_RBM,batch_size_nn,n_iter_nn)
     19     return x,succ_rate,mean_feval

<ipython-input-104-ab640501f743> in main(regularization_nn, learning_rate_RBM, learning_rate_nn, n_iter_RBM, batch_size_RBM, n_iter_nn, batch_size_nn, obj_val, succ_rate, mean_feval)
    252 
    253   # =========================== Calling: initialize() =========================== #
--> 254   smo.initialize()
    255 
    256   # ========================== Calling: GlobalLearning() ======================== #

<ipython-input-104-ab640501f743> in initialize(self)
     69 
     70         # Initialize Global Leader Learning
---> 71         GlobalMin=self.fun_val[0]
     72         GlobalLeaderPosition=self.pos[0,:]
     73         GlobalLimitCount=0

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

i have previously converted my float values as int now i got trouble.... asmo algoithm confising me little bit ...im new to python so its too much to handle ..anyone please guide me

Comment: the issue here is that the numpy array `fun_val` was initialized with 0 length i.e your `batch_size_RBM` has 0 value. And when you are trying to access the first value you cannot because the numpy array has no values in it.

Comment: that means changed values to int causes the problem isn't @Sanchit.Jain.... do you have any idea how to resolve.... because i have the values already...now the value becomes 0... and added to much troble

Comment: can you try printing the `batch_size_RBM`. Changing values to int just crop the decimal points from float nothing else. So i think it is already between [0, 1).

Comment: it would be hard for me to suggest regarding the logical point of view, I would suggest to check the code line by line and see what are the variable values are at different point of time in your code. And please don't try to hurry in implementing python code because it would be hard for you to debug later. Please read about it carefully before implementing.

Comment: ya i know... but sometiems errors kill our sleep.....this code was got from github so  confusing a lot ....if u have any ideas gave suggestion..i'll try to evaluate line by line

Comment: Sorry to hear that i can totally understand that. From my part I'm really sorry but that is the only suggestion i could give.